# How to get link with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the link under a button ('Click Here To Play') on a webpage:

[image]

This is the page inspect in Chrome.

[image]

I am trying to get the highlighted "href" from <a href="https://vidtodo.com/....
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www1.swatchseries.to/freecale.html?r=qepyJmjdCI6Ilo2SWFPdlk51dDBoMSmtxeHFnWXBbVOEJrcVdVMXhPT2t0bUZEZzNtNEd5ZVhCNHYrWnZkT0NZYzdZaWpmZlB0alEiLCJpdiI6IjFmYTdhMzZjYjJhODc1ZmIxODQ4MzVhZDc2N2MyYjNiIiwicyI6Ijc2NTZiMDg0MDFhNmQ1NjYifQ=='
driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a')
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

However, I am getting this as result, rather than the link I want:

```
http://www1.swatchseries.to/

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any suggestions on how to get the link I need?

Comment: https://streamplay.to/ojbcl410357t I got this.

Comment: Hi @arundeepchohan how did you get that? Please post it as an answer, as it's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get link from the `Click Here To Play` button you need to

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and you can use any of the following locator.

**XPATH**:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Click Here to Play']"))).get_attribute("href"))
```

**Css Selector:**

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.push_button.blue"))).get_attribute("href"))
```

Import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a script is dynamically changing the link target (the script is right above the link). It is likely that you're getting the link too early and this shows the placeholder you get.

Try waiting a few seconds, e.g. `time.sleep(5)` and see if that changes the link URL. If that is the case, a proper solution would be a `while` loop checking against the placeholder link, and waiting for it to change to the actual URL.